# Webcam Live Broadcast android

Tags: android, webcam, broadcasting

Yesterday when I was searching for different kinds of apps in Google Play, I found several apps that broadcast live camera feed from the mobile. I made some research like what would be the concept. But could not find many details. Can anyone briefly give some idea? I want to try the same concept in one of my apps.

Ref: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pas.webcam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this Google code project for android ip camera, it used nanoHttpd server for streaming video in android device

http://code.google.com/p/ipcamera-for-android/

download source and try it